# Abstract Factory and Inheritance Kotlin

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin

I'm trying to wrap my head around Kotlin design patterns. I've created my Abstract Factory, using the Kotlin reference as a starting point

```
interface Plant

class OrangePlant : Plant

class ApplePlant : Plant

abstract class PlantFactory {

    abstract fun makePlant(): Plant

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Plant> createFactory(): PlantFactory =
                when (T::class) {
                    OrangePlant::class -> OrangeFactory()
                    ApplePlant::class -> AppleFactory()
                    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
                }
    }
}

class AppleFactory : PlantFactory() {
    override fun makePlant(): Plant = ApplePlant()
}

class OrangeFactory : PlantFactory() {
    override fun makePlant(): Plant = OrangePlant()
```

I'd like all factory instances to inherit from my existing Abstract class `Foo`. How would I do it? Like this? What am I missing? Or have I lost my mind and haven't realised it?

```
interface Plant

class OrangePlant : Plant

class ApplePlant : Plant

abstract class PlantFactory {
    abstract fun makePlant(foo: Foo): Plant

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T : Plant> createFactory(): PlantFactory = when (T::class) {
            OrangePlant::class -> OrangeFactory()
            ApplePlant::class  -> AppleFactory()
            else               -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}

class AppleFactory : PlantFactory() {
    override fun makePlant(): Plant = ApplePlant()
}

class OrangeFactory : PlantFactory() {
    override fun makePlant(): Plant = OrangePlant()
}
```

Or should I be looking to add into the companion object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the inheritance, you should simply say

```
abstract class PlantFactory : Foo() { ... }
```

That will make the `PlantFactory` type inherit from the `Foo` base class. There is no difference from what you have before.

I recommend using `companion object` to implement factory. It makes the code shorted:

```
interface Foo

interface Plant

class OrangePlant : Plant {
    companion object Factory : PlantFactory() {
        override fun makePlant() = OrangePlant()
    }
}

class ApplePlant : Plant {
    companion object Factory : PlantFactory() {
        override fun makePlant() = ApplePlant()
    }
}

abstract class PlantFactory : Foo {
    abstract fun makePlant(): Plant
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val foo1 : PlantFactory = OrangePlant.Factory
    val foo2 : PlantFactory = ApplePlant.Factory

    val orange = foo1.makePlant()
    val apple = foo2.makePlant()
}
```

Also, I removed the `inline fun <reified T : Plant> createFactory():`: Instead of saying `PlantFactory.createFactory<OrangePlant>` you can say `OrangePlant.Factory`.

You may still have that method, in my case, it will be a bit different:

```
inline fun <reified T : Plant> createFactory(): PlantFactory = when (T::class) {
    OrangePlant::class -> OrangePlant.Factory
    ApplePlant::class  -> ApplePlant.Factory
    else               -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
}
```

For the typed hierarchies, it may make sense to use `sealed` classes. Kotlin will allow writing `when` expressions without `else` statement if you cover all child classes

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. 

About inline and reified - I understood that these would would not be immediately compiled, meaning that they wouldn't take up memory unless called and they would be destroyed after executing. Would that be the in your example? @eugene-petrenko

Comment: inline functions will be inlined into the call site, it means, the method bodies will be simplified and put instead of a function call. That is the trick that allows having reified generics working on top of the JVM. It does not require extra memory to run, it only makes your compiled code a bit longer